# Необходима помощь в вёрстке

Tags: html, css

Необходимо создать left-bar и work-place так чтобы было адаптивно до разрешение 1024-768(ipad)

Не могу понять как сдлетьа это адаптивно, использую bootstrap,но он мне особо в этом деле не помогает тк. по шаблону правая колонка всегда 60px.

Основная загвоздка заключается в том что элимент .work-place не помещается если ему задать ширину 100%. Если делать через js то это страшно лагает и особой удобностью не отличается. Как сделать это?

```
//вот код вёрстки
<body>
    <noscript>
        <p>В вашем браузере не включен либо не поддерживается JavaScript. Приложение не может работать!</p>
    </noscript>

    <div class="header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="logo">YU</div>
                    <div class="top-line-tool">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="left-bar">
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="drop-content">
                elements
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="view-box" class="work-place">place</div>
    </div>

    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <script data-main="js/main.js" src="js/require.min.js"></script>
    <!-- SCRIPTS END -->
</body>
```

Вот результат
[image: ваыффвы]

Сам элимент .menu не меняется, а вот .drop-content должен уменьшатся с размером экрана(запросами). При этом поле контента занимает всё свободное пространство.

Вот шаблон который реализую

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Эл**е**мент, сай**д**бар. Самая простая, и, наверное, устаревшая реализация - через флоат с обычным элементом.

Comment: Я нашёл уже решение) спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил данную задачу, сайтбар был сделан фиксированным и расположен по необходимой координате, были составлены медиа-запросы необходимые для отзывчивости сайтбара, поле для работы занимает 100% ширины с внутренним отступом равным ширине сайтбара.

Comment: без примера кода (html,js) ответ выглядит неполным.